# ASP.NET request timeout after 90 seconds - Service Unavailable 503

Tags: asp.net, ajax, timeout, httprequest

My web application (ASP.NET 4.0) makes a call to a server from client-side (using AjaxPro library, but I don’t think it makes any difference). The call is starting a potentially long-running task on the server – sometimes it may tike about 5 minutes to complete. I’m more than happy to wait this time but for some reason my request gets interrupted after exactly 90 seconds – 2 m 60 seconds (according to FireBug). 
It sends back Service Unavailable 503 message. This happens only when I host my application on IIS (7.0), it works without problems (i.e. processes the request for all 5 minutes without interrupting it) on my local PC in debug mode from VS2010 on ASP.NET Development Server.

I have tried several things so far:

- I increased AjaxPro global timeout: AjaxPro.timeoutPeriod = 1000000;
- I modified my web.config file like follows:

  <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="102400" executionTimeout="360" />
  <sessionState timeout="60"></sessionState>
- In IIS Manager -> Sites -> My website -> Advanced Settings I increased value of Connection Time-out (seconds) property.

[image]

- In the application’s application pool -> Advanced Settings I increased all possible timeouts:

[image]

- I tried to increase HttpContext.Current.Server.ScriptTimeout in the server side handler's code.

Noting seemed to help. It works fine on ASP.NET Development server but when it comes to IIS it just cuts off my requests precisely after 90 seconds.

Any thoughts, guys?

Comment: Is it still completing the task? I'm asking because it could potentially be the client. Another question is whether or not the server is has any errors logged from that.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes it is completing the tasks when it is in IIS. I see this from the logs. But apparently it doesn’t do anything i.e. it doesn't send the task results to the client as connection has been already lost. :(

Answer (score 4):

There is another timeout called "AsyncPostBackTimeOut" in asp:ScriptManager set by default precisely to ... 90 secs.

Answer (score 1):

Can you look your web server machine global defaults? Maybe a configuration blocks your request.

system32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config

- http://programming4.us/website/3440.aspx
- [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347568(VS.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347568%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and solved it by adding `AsyncPostBackTimeOut`value as `1000`to my aspx page (which is approx. 17 minutes):

```
            <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" AsyncPostBackTimeOut="1000" runat="server">
        </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
```